# Ghostscript/ embed_fonts() never stops

Tags: r, pdf, extrafont

I want to create a R-plot that uses the font Latin Modern Roman and export it as pdf.
I've found the package `extrafont` that provides such additional fonts. At first, I had some issues with Ghostscript, which was not installed on my computer and after installation was not found. Providing R with the complete path to the .exe like this `Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.52/bin/gswin64.exe")`, however, fixed the problem. Similar to many examples I've found on the internet, I then wrote the following script*:

```
require("extrafont")
loadfonts(device = "win")

dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 20), y = c(
1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 21, 43, 30, 91, 100, 200, 238, 490, 700, 900, 920, 1000
))

file <- paste(fig_dir, "/test.pdf", sep = "")
pdf(file = file, width = 5, height = 5*0.75)
par(family = "LM Roman 10")
plot(x~y, data = dat, main = "LaTeX Font Plot", ylab = "y-lab", xlab = "This is the x-label")
dev.off()
embed_fonts(file = file, outfile = str_replace(file, ".pdf", "_embed.pdf"))
```

Here, `fig_dir` is the directory to a folder containing the exported figures.

The first problem is a warning message telling me that the width of symbol *0x2d* is unknown. Nevertheless, the .pdf is exported. The main issue, however, is the subsequent `embed_fonts()` command, because it simply runs forever. Unfortunately, I won't get any error messages, I just never get a result. Maybe someone has a hint where the problem could be or even faced a similar problem?

*the fonts were previously installed:

```
font_import(prompt = FALSE, pattern = "lmroman")
loadfonts(device = dev)
```

Comment: Hey Manuel! If you are using Windows, my problems with exporting different fonts end, when I started to use the cairo_pdf() function, rather than the normal pdf() function. I do the same as you (using extrafont package), but I did not have to embed the fonts with this cairo_pdf() function.

Comment: Thanks, cairo_pdf() deos the job; great!

Comment: Good that I help. I do not why this is related to cairo (the anti-alising system of Windows), but the Windows have so many problems related to rendering fonts, that I im ok with this solution kkkk.